# Want to scrape data using 10 different keywords in URL for 2 pages and write scraped data to csv using Python 3.6.2 and BS4

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, beautifulsoup

I have the code ready for one keyword and its working fine. Next problem is I want to do the scrape for 10 different keywords and save them in one csv file with the keyword name on column/row. I think we can give csv file as input and it picks keyword one by one and does scrape. Here is the code:

```
import requests    
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

base_url = "http://www.amazon.in/s/ref=sr_pg_2?
rh=n%3A4772060031%2Ck%3Ahelmets+for+men&keywords=helmets+for+men&ie=UTF8"
#excluding page from base_url for further adding
res = []
for page in range(1,3): 
  request = requests.get(base_url + '&page=' + str(page), headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36'}) # here adding page    
  if request.status_code == 404: #added just in case of error
     break
  soup = BeautifulSoup(request.content, "lxml")
  for url in soup.find_all('li', class_ = 's-result-item'):
    res.append([url.get('data-asin'), url.get('id')])
df = pd.DataFrame(data=res, columns=['Asin', 'Result'])    
df.to_csv('hel.csv')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some sample keywords, replace on needed ones.

```
import requests    
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

base_url = "http://www.amazon.in/s/ref=sr_pg_2?rh=n%3A4772060031%2Ck%3Ahelmets+for+men&ie=UTF8"

keywords_list = ['helmets for men', 'helmets for women']
keyword = 'helmets for men'
#excluding page from base_url for further adding
res = []
for page in range(1,3): 
    for keyword in keywords_list:
        request = requests.get(base_url + '&keywords=' + requests.utils.quote(keyword) + '&page=' + str(page), headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36'}) # here adding page    
        if request.status_code == 404: #added just in case of error
            break
        soup = BeautifulSoup(request.content, "lxml")
        for url in soup.find_all('li', class_ = 's-result-item'):
            res.append([url.get('data-asin'), url.get('id'), keyword])

df = pd.DataFrame(data=res, columns=['Asin', 'Result', 'keyword'])    
df.to_csv('hel.csv')
```

Comment: Super Dmitriy..Every thing looks fine. thanks for the code

Comment: yes, you can, use `open` and `csv.reader`, then convert to `list`

Comment: use google, I think >70% of answers on your questions you'll find there=)

Comment: @dimitriy in the above url its looks like the keywords is not replacing in url..I think we need to set counter for keyword or something..

Comment: don't understand you completely, please rephrase

Comment: I hope I got what you mean=) 
So in my loop only `keywords` parameter is changing, but in amazon there are several parameters that organically change when you pass a query in search field or click `next` button. From the other side, as far as I inspected the page output from switching pages manually or building in loop, there's no difference in pages content. So there shouldn't be any problems in using my loop.

Comment: so i have used this url http://www.amazon.in/s/ref=sr_pg_2?rh=n%3A976442031%2Ck%3Awall+stickers&page=2&keywords=wall+stickers&ie=UTF8  and keywords list is 'wall stickers','wall clock','curtains','bedsheets for double bed','photo frames','fan','led bulbs','ceiling fan','wall stickers for bedroom','pillow' i m getting ASIN list of 1st keyword for all the remaining keyword

Comment: I've just opened url that you gave, then replaced manually `keyword` parameter on what I got randomly first - `ceiling+fan` - and I saw different goods on pages. If you're getting same output for different keywords, then reckeck yourself again, might be some mistake somewhere.

Comment: Hello, can you help me with the other question which i have posted. its regarding UI using tkinter.

Comment: Hi, I didn't use `tkinter` at all, so hardly can help you with it, sorry.